# How to eliminate variables with null value using JSON

Tags: java, spring, gson, spring-rest

I am getting json response in below format

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "emp_id": 101,
            "name": null,
            "company": "Onmobile",
            "test_beans": null
        },
        {
            "emp_id": 101,
            "name": null,
            "company": "Onmobile",
            "test_beans": null
        }
    ],
    "organizations": [
        {
            "name": "Google"
        },
        {
            "name": "Facebook"
        }
    ]
}
```

**name** is an attribute of type String and **test_beans** is a reference variable of some class. So, while getting a response I want to exclude those variables which are having null value.
I am using spring rest-api. And I have a custom gsonconverter...so please help me on what needs to do with gson builder so it can eliminate those null variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null values are excluded by default as long as you don't set serializeNulls() to your GsonBuilder.